# How to pass value from one controller to another in LARAVEL?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-7

**GOALS:** I want to pass `autograph` database data to `ImageUploadController.php` from `AutographController.php` basically to determine if the data already existed in the Database.

---

**What I've Done:**

```
if (Autograph::where("$autograph", '=', Input::get('autograph'))->exists()) {
echo "Autograph Registered.";
}
```

---

**But it's giving me this error**

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException

Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Autograph' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\PKL_DSV\resources\views\imageUpload.blade.php)

i already imported `use App\Http\Controllers\AutographController;`

Comment: Can you provide the method in AutographController.php that sent the data and method in ImageUploadController.php that receive the data?

Comment: `Autograph` isn't `AutographController` ... you need to alias, import, the model you are using, that is why the class not found error currently

Comment: `Autograph` is a model, not the Controller, instead of `use App\Http\Controllers\AutographController;`, create a model Autograph and change to `use App\Http\Model\Autograph;`

Comment: your question bit confuse. i think you have `Autograph` model so in your controller you can use it calling `App\Autograph;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to import your model by adding `use App\Autograph` not  `use App\Http\Controllers\AutographController`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
App\Autograph::where("$autograph", '=', Input::get('autograph'))
```

and make sure to use correct namespace. Also, do not pass data between controllers, use models to do whatever you want. If you've to pass data, you can use sessions and flush sessions after use.